# Project MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, project, mysql-workbench

I have this project I have to do and one of the questions states write sql to show report of visits & revenue generated by each room. I have all the tables completed so this should be easy to answer im not very good with mysql so I have no idea how to do it.

Please Help!

the question just needs the roomtables and the visit table so it has something to do with charges and a way to count the visits. I would try to figure this out myself but again im not very good at MySQL.

```
Create Schema Visit;


create table roomtableS(
RoomID char (2)     not null,
RoomNum char (2)    not null,
Charge integer not null,
CONSTRAINT RoomTable_PK Primary Key(RoomID));


Insert into roomtableS values
('01','1A',125.00),
('02','1A',150.00),
('03','1A',100.00),
('04','1A',200.00),
('05','2B',150.00),
('06','2B',125.00),
('07','3C',200.00),
('08','3C',125.00),
('09','3C',100.00);





SELECT * FROM ROOMTABLES;


create table PATIENT(
PatientID    char(5)    not null, 
PatientName  Char(25) not null, 
PatientEmail     Char(30) null,
PatientPhoneNumber Char(10) null,
PatientAddress    Char(100) null,
constraint PATIENT_PK Primary key(PatientID));

insert PATIENT values
('P1', 'Bruce Willis', 'bwillis@mail.org', '2022223333', '1111 Cosmic dr'),
('P2', 'Demi Moore', 'moore@email.net', '2021113333', '1112 Cosmic dr'),
('P3', 'Andre Agassi', 'agassi@mail.org', '2023333333', '1113 Cosmic dr'),
('P4', 'Jet Lee', 'jetlee@email.net', '2023334444', '1114 Chinatown ct'),
('P5', 'Jim Carey', 'carey@email.net', '2023335555', '1115 United dr'),
('P6', 'Bruce Lee', 'bruce@gmail.com', '2023336666', '1115 Chinatown ct');

select* From PATIENT;




Create table SERVICETable(
ServiceID       Char (5) not null,
ServiceTreatment Char(25) not null,
ServiceCost     numeric  not null,
constraint  SERVICE_PK Primary Key(ServiceID));

insert SERVICETable values
('S1','Sore throat', 10.00),
('S2', 'Fever', 15.00),
('S3', 'Headache', 10.00),
('S4', 'Blood pressusre', 20.00),
('S5', 'Yearly checkup', 30.00),
('S6', 'Common cold', 15.00);

select* from SERVICETable;


Create Table doctortable(
DocID char (5)   NOT NULL,
DoctorFirstName char(15) Not NULL,
DoctorLastName char (15) Not Null,
DoctorPhone char (15) Not Null,
CONSTRAINT DoctorTable_PK Primary Key(DocID));


INSERT INTO doctortable values
('D1','Tim','Edward','555-123-4567'),
('D2','Andy','Smith','888-777-6666'),
('D3','John','Smith','222-321-7654');






Select * From doctortable;



Create Table visit(
VisitID char (5) not Null,
PatientID Char (5) not null,
DocID Char (5) not null,
ServiceID Char (5)  not Null,
RoomID char (2) not Null,
Visit date  not null,
CONSTRAINT   VISIT_PK    PRIMARY KEY (VisitID));



Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (PatientID)
references Patient (PatientID);


Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (DocID)
references doctortable (DocID);

Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (ServiceID)
references ServiceTable (ServiceID);

Alter table Visit 
add foreign key (RoomID)
references roomtableS (RoomID);


Insert into Visit (VisitID,PatientID,DocID,ServiceID,RoomID,Visit) values
('V1','P1','D1','S1','05','2014-01-03'),
('V2','P2','D2','S2','01','2014-01-10'),
('V3','P3','D1','S3','02','2014-01-10'),
('V4','P4','D2','S4','07','2014-01-15'),
('V5','P1','D3','S2','08','2014-01-10'),
('V6','P5','D3','S5','03','2014-02-02'),
('V7','P4','D1','S6','06','2014-01-10'),
('V8','P3','D2','S5','03','2014-02-03'),
('V9','P2','D3','S6','01','2014-02-04'),
('V10','P3','D1','S2','06','2014-02-04'),
('V11','P5','D2','S4','04','2014-02-05'),
('V12','P4','D1','S5','09','2014-02-06');


Select * from Visit
```

Comment: This question would be better suited to http://pleasedomyhomeworkforme.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if ur not gonna answer the question than peace

Comment: You're not likely to get much help on this. SO is for discrete questions - something clear and to the point, and your just throwing a bunch of stuff up hoping someone will help. You're not good at MySQL? No biggie, but if you just fish for other people to tell you how to do things, that won't ever change.

Comment: "I would try to figure this out myself but again im not very good at MySQL." Actually TRY, and show us where you get stuck, and people will be a lot more happy to help.

Comment: im stuck on the question..... I dont know what sql statement to use I have to find the count for the visits and the revenue generated by each room.... so it has something to do with charges in the roomtableS and visits from the visit table I just need to know what sql statement to use....

Comment: I think what the others are trying to explain is make an attempt before just posting a what should I use/what should I do question. For example, a simple **Google** Search for [_"mysql count"_](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+count&oq=sql+count&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1238j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql+count) returns some great examples around counting rows. The first result for example, is directly from the development documentation. Have a look at that, give it a go and then come back when you are struggling or when you need help debugging a _MySQL_ error message...

Comment: I would make an attempt if i knew where to start....

Comment: @user3529435 Did you review the **Google** Search I linked to? The top result is to the development documentation, read up on `COUNT()` and `JOIN` and give it a whirl. That's where you should start...